# ¿Como mostrar primero una fila de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Teniendo esta tabla como haria para que la fila numero 3 me aparezca primero en una consulta y que lo demas este como este ..pero que en la consulta aparezcan todos los registros, solo varie el orden

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desearia que quede algo asi el resultado de la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dos cosas: podrías agregar lo que has tratado? indica que versión de mysql estas usando, un extra agrega una muestra de como te gustaría que queden los resultados

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Aparte de lo que te indica @shadow, conviene que digas si la tabla tiene algún criterio de orden (en otra columna) o si simplemente quieres que en tu consulta quede ordenada así de una manera *arbitraría*. Es extraño que la quieras ordenada así sin ningún motivo aparente ¿?

Comment: quiero que con una consulta quede asi

Comment: ¿Cómo hiciste para producir la segunda imagen?

Comment: bueno utilize paint para dar una referencia a como queria que quede

Comment: Ohh con paint no se puede resolver esto. Entonces, ¿no hay ninguna otra columna por la que ordenar?

Comment: no, solo quiero que la columna 3 este primero, la verdad no se si esque es posible

Comment: Puedes hacer algo así: `SELECT * FROM tuTabla ORDER BY (id_carrera=3) DESC;` así te pondrá de primero la carrera 3 de forma arbitraria.

Comment: si, me sirvio muchas gracias en verdad

Comment: @MiguelQuispe Recuerda si una respuesta te fué útil, entonces debes marcarla como aceptada dando clic en la palomita del lado izquierdo que aparece junto a dicha respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez pueda servirte utilizando el operador "UNION", en una primera consulta
extraes la fila con id 3, en una segunda consulta extraes todas las filas con identificador distinto de 3 y los ordenas ascendentemente por id, para posteriormente utilizar operador UNION  y unir los resultados de ambas consultas y obtener lo que quieres.

```
 ( SELECT *
   FROM tuTabla
   WHERE id = 3
 )
 UNION
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM tuTabla
   WHERE id != 3
   ORDER BY id ASC
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes establecer un orden arbitrario haciendo esto:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tuTabla 
ORDER BY (id_carrera=3) DESC;
```

Si por ejemplo, quieres todas las otras ordenadas, menos esa, puedes hacer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tuTabla 
ORDER BY (id_carrera=3) DESC, id_carrera;
```

O también establecer otro orden por otra columna, teniendo siempre la `3` en primero:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tuTabla 
ORDER BY (id_carrera=3) DESC, nombre;
```